# How to improve performance of row-wise calculation in nested ifelse?

Tags: r, performance, if-statement, row

In this forum I found a nice way to do row-wise calculation of values in R, which are then stored in a newly created column (c3).

In the code provided below the nested ifelse() statement examplifies an example with three levels (a1 ranges from 1 to 3).

```
a1 <-   1 # variable 1; for this example it's either 1 or not.
a2 <-   2 # range: up to 10 values (e.g. for this example 1:10)

c1 <- c(1:6)   # column 1 as sample data set
c2 <- c(11:16) # column 2 as sample data set

# column 3 calculated based on row wise operations
c3 <- ifelse(a1==1 & a2==1,1,ifelse(a1==1 & a2==2,2,ifelse(a1==1 & a2==3,3,4))) 

r <- t(rbind(c1,c2,c3))
r
```

Now I need the `ifelse()` statement nested 10 (!) times (at least). Something like

```
ifelse(a1 == 1 & a2 ==1,,ifelse(a1 == 1 & a2 ==2,,ifelse(a1 == 1 & a2 ==3,,ifelse(a1 == 1 & a2 ==4,,ifelse(a1 == 1 & a2 ==5,,ifelse(a1 == 1 & a2 ==6,,ifelse(a1 == 1 & a2 ==7,,ifelse(a1 == 1 & a2 ==8,,ifelse(a1 == 1 & a2 ==9,,)))))))))
```

While such a nested `ifelse()` statement might be fine for 2 or 3 levels, I wonder if there is a more efficient (faster performing) way to do these 10 nested row-wise manipulations.

May I add: depending on the level of nesting different calculations have to be done. Thus for example (1) looks in real life more like (2).

```
(1) ifelse(a1==1 & a2==1,1, etc)
(2) ifelse(a1==1 & a2==1,variable1*(1+variable2 /variable3), etc)
```

System: Mac OS X Mavericks, RStudio: R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)

Comment: `t(rbind())` can be written just as `cbind()`

Comment: What would the next `ifelse` look like in `(2)`. Is it for example `ifelse(a1==1 & a2==1,variable1*(1+variable2 /variable3), ifelse(a1==1 & a2==2,variable1*(2+variable2 /variable3), etc))`

Comment: You could reorganize your nested if-else structure by some boolean algebra to avoid redundant comparisons. `ifelse(a1==1, ifelse(a2==1, 1, ifelse(a2==2, 2, ifelse(a2==3, 3, 4))), 4)` is equivalent to your calculation of `c3`

Comment: response to comment2: this would be for example ifelse(a1==1 & a2==1,variable1*(1+variable2 /variable3), ifelse(a1==1 & a2==2,variable4*(2+variable6 /variable7), etc))

Comment: response to comment3: that already looks much nicer. Thanks!

Comment: No ifelse is needed for `c3 <- (a1==1)*((a2<4)*a2 + (a2>=4)*4)`

Answer (score 1):

Create a lookup table:

```
lookup=data.frame(a=rep(1:2, 2), b=rep(1:2, each=2), value=1:4)

c3 = with(lookup, lookup[a==a1 & b==a2,]$value)

cbind(c1,c2,c3)
```

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. Have not used look up yet, but will read about it. Thank your very much!

Comment: Lookup will also be the best solution if your values are different (other numeric, characters, etc) or more numerous.

Comment: Sorry, I am not advanced enough to combine the lookup-table with my ifelse statement .... May I ask for advice again? It really seems to be a great way to do this 'matching' with various variables. Thanks so much!

Comment: The point is that you do not need ifelse anymore - as described in the example - to build c3 ...Just put your value of a1 and a2 and that's all!

Comment: why do I get the error "undefined columns selected" with your statement? To replace the ifelse statement seems a brilliant option. Thanks a million for your patience!

Comment: Maybe because I put `b1` instead of `a2` and forgot a comma: edited!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74725/discussion-between-user2006697-and-colonel-beauvel).

Comment: I can't chat from my firm, the linked is blocked by some firewall I cant deactivate.

Comment: ok.just followed the advice not to provide too many comments. Again thanks a million for all help!